# cassandra heap usage - what takes the space?

Tags: cassandra

I have 14GB heap on my cassandra servers, 11GB for old gen.
Using jstat -gcutil I see 73% usage of the old gen - when there is no operations on cassandra.
How can I see what's takes all the space?

thanx,
Pavel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is a page in the Cassandra documentation about this topis.](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html)

For one, it is documented there that you shouldn't have a heap greater than 8 GB. The GC pauses will get too long.

Other than that, see the page for more information:

> The Cassandra metadata resides in memory and is proportional to total
>   data. Some of the components [grow proportionally to the size of total memory](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_about_reads_c.html?scroll=concept_ds_vrp_4qx_zj__image_t4g_frx_zj).

If you have Cassandra 1.2 and later (and have JNA enabled), the parts that grow proportionally to memory should be stored off-heap, though.

To be completely sure, though, you can always [analyze the heap](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+analyze+heap).